# Como hago para quedarme en la página que estaba con un alert y no redigirme al envio de phpmailer

Tags: javascript, php, html

estoy trabajando con phpmailer soy bastante nuevo en esto y resulta que tengo el contact form que envia el mail correctamente todo, pero me redirige al archivo php con el que se hizo todo el trabajo, porque claramente está puesto en action=. Yo quiero que se quede en la web que estaba, borre lo que se escribió en contact-form y me salte un alerta que diga "mensaje enviado". Cómo debería proceder?

En mi contact form tengo esto:

```
<form action="php/envio.php" method="POST" id="contactForm" class="form_contact">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="cname" type="text" class="form-control-input" id="cname" required>
                        <label class="label-control" for="cname">Nombre Completo</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="cphone" type="number" class="form-control-input" id="cphone" required>
                        <label class="label-control" for="cphone">Teléfono</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="cmail" type="email" class="form-control-input" id="cemail" required>
                        <label class="label-control" for="cemail">Email</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="cmessage" class="form-control-textarea" id="cmessage" required></textarea>
                        <label class="label-control" for="cmessage">Mensaje</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="form-control-submit-button">Enviar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Y en el archivo php de envio tengo todo lo obvio de configuración y al final dentro del try tengo:

```
$mail->send();
        header('Location:../mensaje-de-envio.html');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "El mensaje no pudo ser enviado. Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
```

Obviamente con ese código estoy redigiriendo la validación correcta del email a una página de mensaje enviado correctamente... pero eso estaba probando pero no me gusta... quiero mantenerme en la página original con un alert y listo, y un clean del contact form.. como puedo proceder?

Comment: Tendrás que enviar el formulario por Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno basicamente no encontré la manera "perfecta" de hacerlo pero una muy buena, adjunto código:

```
$mail->send();
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Mensaje enviado correctamente")';
        echo '</script>';
        header("Refresh:1; url=../index.html");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "El mensaje no pudo ser enviado. Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
```

De esa manera, me muestra una alert y carga la pagina principal al segundo